# How do I secure my Lenovo ThinkPad tablet against thieves when it doesn't have a Kensington lock?

Tags: security, lenovo-thinkpad-tablet

The manual for the Lenovo ThinkPad doesn't say that it has a Kensington-like lock device on it, so are there any other ways for me to secure it against thieves?

I'd like to secure my tablet against the knobs that you can secure Kensington locks around. I know that Kensington locks aren't completely secure, but they can at least deter the vast majority of thieves.

Comment: You want to secure it, but where? On a kiosk? Coffee table? Backpack? On your cat? You need to be more precise! And it's not like Kensington locks are secure . There's absolutely no way that you could stop a thief that's smart enough.

Comment: *I'd like to secure my tablet against the knobs* that made me chuckle because, due to differences in culture and what-nots, "knob" is a slang for something else...

Answer (score 2):

I believe your question is trying to ask 'Are there any laptop security devices out there that do not use a kensington lock slot?' The answer is, Yes.

To see a nice list of various types of locks that are available for notebooks and laptops, please [see this website](http://www.computersecurity.com/laptop/index.html?ga_campaign=%28roi%29%20laptop%20security&ga_adgroup=laptop%20anti%20theft&ga_keyword=laptop%20anti%20theft&gclid=CInupK2FkLACFUFo4Aod4kQlqw).

I in no way endorse this seller, however they are one of the few sites that seem to have a nice listing of many kensington-alternative locking devices for laptops. I am merely using it for informative purposes.